# Adwhirl Ads in Ipad

Tags: ipad, adwhirl

Hi  I am Developing a universal App.i am showing adWhirl Ads on Iphone.its Working Fine
Now i want to display the Ads in Ipad.i have small doubts regarding this...

```
1)Is there any Configuration changes in Adwhirl For Ipad 
2)Can I use Same Adwhirl Api For Iphone And Ipad 
3)How can i Change Frames specific to ipad
```

Can Any one help me to get out of this

Answer (score 3):

I did exactly what you want to do and I wrote a tutorial for others and for myself to remember what I did.

Here it is: [Universal Adwhirl (UIKit)](http://goosesoft.com/blog/universal-adwhirl-uikit/)

If you happen to be working on a cocos2d game take a look at this: [Universal Adwhirl Ads in Cocos2d](http://goosesoft.com/blog/universal-adwhirl-ads-in-cocos2d-2/)