# Adwhirl iPad Support

Tags: ios, ipad, adwhirl

I am trying to add AdWhirl to my Universal application. But there is something that i could not figure it out. While integrating AdWhirl to universal application, i have to add both  AdWhirl SDK Keys to my app. (as they said on all tutorials.) But there is no option for iPad on AdWhirls new application interface. There is only Android and iPhone.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: [Adwhirl Ads in Ipad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087834/adwhirl-ads-in-ipad)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that iPad works the same as iPhone unless otherwise stated.